# "net,rim.device.internal.io.CriticallOException: Critical tunnel failure" what does this error is?

Tags: blackberry

The application is running perfect in device and simulator when i do use via eclipse, but when i will give cod file to client, it gives the following error, any idea?

this is the error:

net,rim.device.internal.io.CriticallOException: Critical tunnel failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your network connection in another thread

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
         //connection stuff
    }
}.start();
```

And add these settings to your url

```
String url += ";deviceside=true"
if(apn != null && !apn.trim.equals("")){
    url += ";apn="+apn;
}
```

More information here http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Critical-tunnel-failure/td-p/416396

Comment: @Veer, Are you using any web service call ? Connection to a website ? It should be at this place, where you do those kind of calls. Without any code from your part, I can't help you more.

Comment: just last that what apn is, datatype of apn?

Comment: @Veer, from what I've read, you have to know these settings for each carrier. I would suggest to not add these settings to the connection. Just add the deviceside=true. Anyway, wihtout any code sample, or more information on the client device, I can't really help more than this.